# Is there a website that lists the coupon websites for each country?

Tags: budget, online-resources, shopping

A good way of saving money while traveling is to use a ['coupon' website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deal_of_the_day), where you can often get bargains on items such as hotel stays or restaurant meals. In Czech Republic the main website is called [Slevomat](https://www.slevomat.cz/) and I know that [Groupon](https://www.groupon.com/) is popular in the US.

Is there a website that lists these coupon website for each country?

Comment: Is this not service-shopping? (for websites)

Comment: @AakashM no, I don't need specific sites, I just need a way of *finding* such sites for when I travel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SimilarWeb](https://www.similarweb.com), a company which provides digital market intelligence, has a list of the [global top 50 coupon shopping sites](https://www.similarweb.com/top-websites/category/shopping/coupons), which can be seen and linked to outside the paywall. Its resources covers hundreds of topics across multiple industries (travel, insurance, e-commerce, ad-tech, agencies, publishing).